# Excel VBA autofill every other second

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to fill some cells, but I want the code to wait one second in every loop:

```
Sub fill()
Dim i As Long, j As Long


i = 133
j = 134
For x = 1 To 5
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Selection.Autofill Destination:=Range("L" & i & ":L" & j), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("L131:L132").Select
    i = i + 1
    j = j + 1
Next x
End Sub
```

I constantly get the following error: Run-time error 1004:
AutoFill method of Range class failed
Thanks for the help.

Comment: There's no selection at first?

Comment: I took that part from the record macro tool.

Comment: I also put the selection first. No change

Comment: I suggest to do and record the whole process 5 times just to check where the error may be... I'm sure you missed something...

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I want to use variables for cell values. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Just one cell. I want to fill the same formula many times. The formula actually a module which calls any api. There is a time limit how many times can the api being called, that's why I need to imply the Wait into the code.

Comment: What cell is the formula in to start?

Comment: well... i dont know exactly what you are doing at the end... but would it not be easier to pull the data in vba in an array and then print them at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Scott Craner's suggestion this is the working code:

```
Sub fill()
Dim i As Long, j As Long


i = 134

For x = 1 To 5
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Range("L" & i) = "=Formula(J" & i & ")"
    i = i + 1

Next x
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: I will but stackowerflow doesn't let me accept my own answer for 2 more days

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning the formula directly:

```
Sub fill()
Dim i As Long, j As Long


i = 133
j = 134
For x = 1 To 5
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Range("L" & i & ":L" & j).Formula = Selection.Formula
    i = i + 1
    j = j + 1
Next x
End Sub
```

If all you want is the corresponding formula in column L from Column J then this should do it:

```
Sub fill()
Dim i As Long

For i = 133 To 137
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Range("L" & i).Formula = Range("J" & i).Formula
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks good but I don't know how should I put the formula into it. I would like the get the following result: for the "L133" cell: =Formula(J133) and so on

Comment: Then the line would be `Range("L" & i).Formula = Range("J" & i).Formula`

Comment: Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.
Additional information: the J133 cell contains only a value (actually a string), and the formula uses that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

```
Sub fill()
Dim i As Long, j As Long

i = 133
j = 134
For x = 1 To 5
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Range("L131:L132").Autofill Destination:=Range("L" & i & ":L" & j), Type:=xlFillDefault
    i = i + 1
    j = j + 1
Next x
End Sub
```